# RoR - Sessions not working correctly (Log in/out)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

Okay I created a user and a login form and added a session support. It shows the login form correctly. I log in and it shows the message "Logged in!". Working correctly here.

But still it shows me the login field. I added a "Logout" link there too, that if a user is logged in, show log out. But it gives me the logged in successfully message and also the login form.

Here is the application.html.erb file

```
<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="/gfx/logo.png">
        <span>Welcome</span>
        <% if current_user %>
            <%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path %>
        <% else %>
            <%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
                <%= text_field_tag :username, nil, placeholder: "username" %>
                <%= password_field_tag :password, nil,  placeholder: "password" %>
                <%= submit_tag "Log In" %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</header>
```

The sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:userid] = user.id
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged in!"
    else
        flash[:error] = "Wrong Username or Password."
        redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:userid] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out."
  end

end
```

The application controller:

```
private

def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end

helper_method :current_user
```

And the users controller(create) action:

```
def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)

  if @user.save
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to @user, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: When you create the session you're using `session[:userid]` and when you check if a user's logged in you're using `session[:user_id]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session` in the `destroy` and `create` methods looks wrong. Change it from `session[:userid]` to `session[:user_id]`

In `destroy`:

```
session[:user_id] = nil
```

In `create`:

```
session[:user_id] = user.id
```

Comment: An even better way is to do `session.delete(:user_id)` which will erase the `:user_id` key of the `session` hash, not just set it to `nil`.